# Can I use Google Calendar's website to edit an Exchange calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, synchronization, exchange-server

I want to be able to edit an Exchange calendar with the Google Calendar website, but so far I have only been able to view the Exchange calendar *(by going to "Other Calendars" in the Google Calendar website, then "Add by URL", and finally adding the Exchange calendar's URL).*

The Android version of Google Calendar allows editing of Exchange calendars, which it gains access to when adding an Exchange account to the mail app on a phone.

Is there a way to gain write-access to an Exchange calendar from within the Google Calendar website?

Answer (score 1):

At this time it's not a feature included in the Google Calendar web UI, by the other hand as far as I know, the Google Calendar web UI can't be extended in such way.

The alternative is to use a third party app o built your own, but that is out of the scope of this site.

---

**References**
[Google Calendar Help](http://support.google.com/calendar)